# Name 'hometext' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to Visual Studio, asp.net and C#. I've just managed to create a database that pulls headline text, an image and main text from my table and displays these on my webpage. I want the main text on my homepage to only show the first 200 characters of the main text. In my aspx file I have the following:

```
<asp:DataList ID="HomeList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Itemtemplate>
        <div id ="titlerecent"><asp:Label ID="hometitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HomeHeader") %>'/>  </div>
        <br /><p><asp:Label ID="hometext" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HomeText") %>'/>   </p>
        <div id='resize'><asp:Image ID="homeimage" runat="server" ImageUrl ='<%#"images/" + Eval("HomeImg") %>' /></div>
    </Itemtemplate>     
</asp:DataList>
```

That all displays grand but my difficulty now is accessing the hometext.Text
I'm not sure if and how I am able to do this so that I can change the amount of characters I want to display.
I have been trying the code below in my aspx.cs file to firstly store the text in a string variable but it produces an error 'The name hometext does not exist in the current context' If anybody can please help I would be very grateful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String str = hometext.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to handle that in the `DataList.ItemDataBound` event and call e.item.findcontrol("hometext"). I'm rusty on the exact syntax but that event is called for each item in the datalist.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the vb, but you should be able to convert this to c# easily enough

```
Private Sub HomeList_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As DataListItemEventArgs) Handles HomeList.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim x As Label = e.Item.FindControl("hometext")
        x.Text = Left(x.Text, 200)
    End If

End Sub
```